# How to disable stdin echo in windows console

Tags: ruby, windows, console, stdin

I'm writting a Ruby program for windows, and I need to read user input from keyboard (stdin).

However, it's needed that the user key-presses are not automatically displayed in the windows console, and behave like "silent key presses"

This problem in Ruby over linux, can be solved using the "stty" linux command:

```
%x{stty -icanon -echo}
```

because it is the linux terminal who automatically outputs the user-keys into the terminal, so running the "stty" command tells the terminal to stop showing the user-key-presses.

But my program must run in windows, so I tried searching for a "stty" equivalent command for windows console, but still found nip...

?any suggestions, pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/) gem. To clarify, look at `ask` method and provide a block to silence it's output. It is well exemplified in their [documentation](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/)

Comment: Could you be a litle more specific? I've read though the Highline gem, but did not spoted the "bright solution"...

Comment: Added more details, in the provided link you could have just click on documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is funny, that actually, since then I've also found the rb-readline gem, and now I see that in a pure-case-of-luck, I had an answer from you too - So I'm very gratefull to you :)